# Javascript encrypting password before form submit

Tags: c#, javascript

is there a way to do two way encryption in javascript?

Comment: What purpose would this serve?

Comment: Why secure one part of it, when you left the other (database) end wide open?

Comment: I trust that my database is secured however I dont want the password to pass through network unencrypted, some eavesdropper might be able to retrieve it from network packets. thats why I need some encryption to be done before submitting the form

Comment: Then use SSL so that the entire connection is secured.

Comment: "I trust that my database is secured" - a bad assumption to make.  Everything is compromisable in some way.

Answer (score 9):

> I store plain password text in my database and not the hash value.

Don't do that. People are trusting you with their passwords. It is your responsibility to [protect them](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Password_Storage_Rules).

> I wish to encrypt the password before sending to my server, and my server can decrypt it back to plain text using C#. Anyone know what javascript encryption is suitable for my case?

None. The only system suitable for protecting data being transferred between the browser and the server is SSL. Use the HTTPS scheme.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Quentin that saving users password in plain format is bad idea.

For safe data encryption you can use some asymetric cryptography algorithm for example RSA. Your public key will be saved in javascript side, and C# server will have private key to decrypt received cipher text using RSA.

Answer (score 0):

If you're server can decrypt a password to plain text, then the evil guy can too,

you should send the password to the server as plain text, then convert it to a regular format like `md5()` or `sha1()` then store it in your database as is.

Then when an user wants to login, encrypt the password input and compare it to the one you stored before.

If you want to secure the data transfer from the client to your server, you should use https to make sure data can't be intercepted.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

The best way to encrypt using Javascript in my personal opinion is using SHA-1. Don't use MD5 it is the worst (too easy to decrypt). You can use this library: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha1.html

And use it this way:

```
var encrypted_password = hex_sha512(plain_password);
```

The drawback with Javascript is that adding a password salt ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)) would be clueless because their is no way to give it to the browser without allowing everyone to get the salt of anyone (otherwise you can't encrypt the password).

The most secure is still encryption on the server-side using HTTPS for this specific reason, otherwise this library will do the job very easily.

Comment: That's a one-way hash, not encryption.